# VB.net No rows returned when assigning class object to datagrid

Tags: vb.net

I create a matchwinner object using

```
Public Class matchwinner
    Public Property _hwp As Double
    Public Property _dwp As Double
    Public Property _awp As Double
End Class
```

and assign as follows

```
Dim mw As matchwinner = New matchwinner
    mw._hwp = Int(100 * (1 / hw)) / 100
    mw._dwp = Int(100 * (1 / dw)) / 100
    mw._awp = Int(100 * (1 / aw)) / 100
```

When debugging, mw has the three variables correctly assigned I then try to assign to datagrid as

```
 dgMW.DataSource() = mw
```

but my datagrid has no rows, just the headers I've preset.

if I set rows to be say 5, so that I can see the datagrid with 5 rows at run time, when the above runs it just removes the preset rows.

I tried setting column(x).name to be the variables I want in case it needed to match those up but that didn't work.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the class I've created but not really sure what.

Comment: Add `mw` to a `List(Of matchwinner)` and use that as your `DataSource`.

Comment: perfect - Thank Jim

I did try something similar to generate a level higher, but didn't use list of

much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A DataGridView need to be bound to a collection of objects. It'll make one column per property, and one row for each object if finds in the list

The simplest solution (assuming you're working with forms) to your problem would be to add a dataset to your project, open it, right click the surface and add a datatable, add columns of particular types and names to the table, save and build, then switch to the form designer, open the data sources window, expand the dataset node and drag the datatable node out of the datasources window and onto the form designer

You'll end up with a grid, bound to the datatable, and you can add rows of data in code and they will show in the grid.

[Here's what it could look like - GIF animation screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgoE6.gif)

Comment: Seems if you are adding a birth date, age should be a calculated field.